# More than 2 dynamic layout options per controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, dynamic-programming, rails7

Using multiple `layout` statements in Rails will throw an error.  Rails ignores all but the last `layout` statement.

However, I have a complicated layout system where I need to dynamically render several different layouts other than the standard application layout (the `layout` option in a controller allows for just one alternative layout, the rest defaulting to `app/layouts/application.html.erb`).  I was hoping the following would be a good substitute:

In this case, I'm using a `static_controller.rb` to render the following static content pages (`about.html.erb, contact.html.erb, careers.html.erb, help.html.erb, home.html.erb, landing.html.erb, legal.html.erb, and policies.html.erb`).

1. `landing.html.erb` will have a custom, full-page layout with no header or footer.
2. `about`, `contact`, `home`, and `legal` will each follow the "main" layout [`app/views/layouts/main.html.erb`].
3. `careers`, `help`, and `policies` will each follow the "not_main" layout [`app/views/layouts/not_main.html.erb`].

I need something similar to this in the target `controller`:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
...
layout 'full', :only => [:landing]

%w[about contact home legal ].each do |static_page|
  layout 'main'
end

%w[careers help policies].each do |static_page|
  layout 'not_main'
end
...
def about
end
...
end #Closes the Static Controller
```

This would be preferable to setting the layout in each action call.  However, Rails continues to ignore the previous layout statements, even though they are wrapped in a `%w` array.  Any ideas how to make something like this work?

Comment: probably better to set the layout as an option on the render for each method, e.g. `render layout: "main"`  when rendering the view for the methods about, contact, home and legal, etc.

Comment: That kinda violates the DRY principle.  I was hoping to modularize the code as much as possible.  What I can't figure out is why both arrays are being evaluated when only one has its condition met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on Rails7:

```rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  layout :select_layout

private
  def select_layout
    "main" if %w[about contact home legal].include? action_name
    "full" if %w[landing].include? action_name
    # ...etc
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  layout 'full', only: [:landing]
  layout 'main', only: [:about, :contact, :home, :legal]
  layout  'not_main', only: [:careers, :help, :policies]

  .....
end
```

Comment: This is the format that I had in a previous version of Rails, but it no longer works.  Rails ignores the previous `layout` statements and only parses the last one.  In this scenario, `landing`, `about`, `contact`, `home`, and `legal` would all be ignored and default to the `application.html.erb` template.